# como generar un timer asincrono?

Tags: c#

Necesito controlar las sesiones de usuarios, por esta razón he pensado en el login preguntar si existe alguna sesión en la base de datos relacionada al usuario que se está logrando.

sí existe una sesión activa se debe preguntar si desea cambiarla.(si cambia o su session no está activa continúa con lo siguiente)

si el usuario desea cambiar la sesión se realiza lo siguiente:

- Ejecuta un random que genera un número al azar y se pasa la a ventana principal.
- Después se genera un timer que se debe ejecutar cada 2 minutos repetitivamente y al llegar al final, éste debe realizar un select a la base de datos con un número generado aleatoriamente através de un Random (ya genere el número) y verificar si el número sigue siendo igual o distinto.
- Si el número es igual no se debe hacer nada
- Si el número es distinto se debe cerrar la aplicación (windows form).

Tengo la idea, pero necesito orientación programática.

(hasta el momento  me falta programar el timer con el select ) el timer debe ser asíncronico de manera que la aplicación no se cuelgue mientras realiza el select

```
         private void bunifuThinButton21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        borramensajeerror();
                        if (validacion())
                        {
                            erroricono.Clear();

                            if (txt_rut.Text.Equals("") || txt_contraseña.Text.Equals(""))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("ingresar todos los campos");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (!validarRut(txt_rut.Text))
                                {
                                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("usuario o contraseña incorrecto");
                                    txt_rut.Focus();
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    logear(this.txt_rut.Text, this.txt_contraseña.Text);
                                }


                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception f)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show(f.Message + f.StackTrace, "errror tipo 11");
                    }
                }

     public void logear(string rut, string pass)
            {
                try {




                    //con.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select run_usuario, id_tipousuario, id_estado, id_session, password from tb_usuarios_adm where run_usuario = '"+rut+"' AND password= '"+pass+"'", conexion.obtenerConexion());
                    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    // si lee
                    if(dt.Rows.Count == 1){

                        //identifica el tipo
                        if(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "1")
                        {

                            //identifica el estado
                            if (dt.Rows[0][2].ToString() == "1")
                            {
                                //identifica la session
                                if(dt.Rows[0][3].ToString() == "1") {
                                    //this.Hide();
                                    //new administrador.Principal_administrador(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()).Show();

                                    if (dt.Rows[0][4].ToString() == "excsa")
                                    {
                                        new cambio_contraseña_inicio(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()).ShowDialog();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        this.Hide();
                                        new administrador.Principal_administrador(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()).ShowDialog();
                                    }

                                }else{

                                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("desea cambiar de session", "usuario activo", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
                                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                                    {

                                    }
                                    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
                                    {

                                        MessageBox.Show("el otro usuario continua activo");

                                    }
                                    else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
                                    {

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            else {
                                MessageBox.Show("estado bloqueado");
                            }


                            //identifica el tipo
                        }else if (dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "2")
                        {

                            //identifica el estado
                            if (dt.Rows[0][2].ToString() == "1")
                            {

                                //identifica la session
                                if(dt.Rows[0][3].ToString() == "1") {

                                    Random rdn = new Random();
                                    int a = rdn.Next(1000,9000);

                                    loginprocedimiento procedimiento = new loginprocedimiento();
                                    procedimiento.session(txt_rut.Text, a);


                                    this.Hide();
                                    new operaciones.principal_operaciones(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(), a.ToString()).Show();


                            if (dt.Rows[0][4].ToString() == "excsa")
                            {
                                new cambio_contraseña_inicio(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()).Show();
                            }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("desea cambiar de session", "usuario activo", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
                                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                                    {
                                    //se genera el random para obtener el numero aleatorio
                                        Random rdn = new Random();
                                        int a = rdn.Next(1000, 9000);
                                     // atraves de procedimiento actualizo el campo session del usuario en la base de datos
                                        loginprocedimiento procedimiento = new loginprocedimiento();
                                        procedimiento.session(txt_rut.Text, a);

                                        this.Hide();
// paso al siguiente formulario el rut y la variable generada
                                        new 
operaciones.principal_operaciones(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(), a.ToString()).Show();

                                    }
                                    else if (result == DialogResult.No)
                                    {

                                        MessageBox.Show("la otra session continua activa");

                                    }else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel){

                                    }


                                }
                            }else{
                                MessageBox.Show("estado bloqueado");
                            }
                        }

                    }else{
                        MessageBox.Show("usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto");

                    }
                     }
                catch (Exception f) { 
                    //MessageBox.Show("ingrese caracteres validos");
                }finally{
                    //con.Close();

                    conexion.obtenerConexion().Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: acabo de leer, re-leer, y editar tu pregunta y sigo sin entender. ¿Podrías colocar el código por favor? Quizás compilando con la vista pueda procesar lo que deseas hacer. Saludos :D

Comment: lo que deseo realizar es controlar las sesiones de los usuarios en c#. lo pense de la manera que explique mas arriba.

Comment: 1 si un usuario esta con logeado y desea ingresar de otro pc con su misma cuenta la primera se debe cerrar automaticamente en el fondo eso es lo que quiero lograr

Comment: Con el código y esto último que mencionas te entendí perfectamente. A modo de recomendación, juega con SignalR, te permite mandar notificaciones desde el server a diversos clientes, te dejo un enlace como punto de partida: https://damienbod.com/2013/11/01/signalr-messaging-with-console-server-and-client-web-client-wpf-client/ Saludos, éxitos y bendiciones :D

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de SignalR yo recomiendo entrar en las Reactive Extensions, permite manejar de una mejor manera operaciones asíncronas:

```
// en algún lugar tienes un método que realiza la búsqueda de forma asíncrona 
private async Task<bool> RandomExiste(int randomVal) 
{
    var found = false;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // abres la conexión 
        await connection.OpenAsync();     
        // haces el query     
        await reader.ReadAsync();
        // obtienes el resultado
        found = ... 
    }
    // bla bla bla
   return found;
} 


// ya en la parte donde vas a crear el "timer"   
Observable  // Utilizamos el objeto Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))    // utilizamos interval para que emita cada dos minutos
    .Select(_ => a) // obtenemos el valor random que generaste
    .SelectMany(async randomABuscar => await claseConMetodos.RandomExiste(randomABuscar)) // ejecutamos la query con el valor obtenuido en el select anterior y nos regresa true o false
    .Where(resultado => !resultado) // filtramos que solo procese los resultados falsos (del resultado del selectmany)
    .Subscribe(_ => this.Close()); // cerramos la ventana al terminar
```

claseConMetodos es tu clase donde tienes tus métodos para operaciones crud, y RandomExiste realiza una búsqueda pasándole el número random cómo parámetro, y regresa verdadero o falso.

Agregas el paquete nuget llamado "System. Reactive", y donde vayas a utilizar los Observable solo necesitas agregar:

```
using System.Observables;
using System.Observables.Linq;
```